# Смысл использования removeEventListener

Tags: javascript

Появился вопрос при чтении [раздела документации](https://learn.javascript.ru/introduction-browser-events#addeventlistener-%D0%B8-removeeventlistener) js по addEventListener и removeEventListener.

Зачем использовать removeEventListener, если мы можем убрать/закомментировать строку, где обработчик добавляется с помощью addEventListener?

Comment: Ну допустим, добавили вы событие для какого либо элемента, что если это событие должно быть убрано или отключено после каких либо действий пользователя? Комментировать его будете?

Comment: @Klym а, то есть, допустим, элемент реагирует на первый клик, затем события удаляются, а повторные нажатия ни к чему не приведут? не мог догадаться о практическом применении этого метода, спасибо

Comment: да, вы всё правильно поняли.